# How to switch views in Sencha Touch according to htm events?

Tags: html, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, uiswitch

I would like to switch views according to a html events : typically a tap on a mapped image.

I went trough this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751329/can-you-trigger-action-events-in-sencha-touch-from-html-elements). It explains how to get the href value by adding a listener on the html element. I have succesfully performed this step.

Next step is to switch to the correct view. Typically, if href = "item1" then I want to switch to view "item1"... I do not really get how to perform this.

Code for html element in my view :

```
<img class="map" src="folder/name_pic.jpg" ...usemap='#MapName' />
    <map name='#MapName' ...>
        <area shape=...... href="view1" />
        <area shape=...... href="view2" />
        <area shape=...... href="view3" />
    </map>
```

Code in the parent Tab panel :

```
panel.getEl().on({
    tap: function(e){

        var href = Ext.fly(e.getTarget(
                    'img.map')).getAttribute('href');

        // What goes HERE?
        // if (href == 'view1')
        //     display 'view1'...
},
delegate: 'img.map'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully achieved my goal using "routes" solution in a controller.

First I define my mapped picture as follow :

```
<img class="map" src="folder/name_pic.jpg" ...usemap='#MapName' />
     <map name='#MapName' ...>
         <area shape=...... href="/#view1" />
         <area shape=...... href="/#view2" />
         <area shape=...... href="/#view3" />
     </map>
```

And then in a Controller.js :

```
config: {
    routes: {
        'view1': 'showView1',
        'view2': 'showView2',
        'view3': 'showView3'
    },
[...... code here...]

showView1: function() {

    this.getMainPanel().add({
        xtype: 'view1'
    });
},
showView2: function() {

    this.getMainPanel().add({
        xtype: 'view2'
    });
},
```

That works but does not seem optimal for me. I'll keep working on that!

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using a sample code  shown below,  you might have to modify it for your application design, but this is the general way

```
Tapped: function() {
        // When the user taps on this item, create a new reference new viw, 
        // and set  it as the active item

        Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.create('Your new view Goes here'));
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks but how to make the difference on which part of the pic is tapped? I think about using the "routes" solution in the controller.